# QgsJsonExporter preserve attributes order in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geojson

I've a memory layer i created that i would like to export in GeoJson.
If i add it to main canvas, the attributes table preserve attributes order.

```
# Attributes order preserved
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
ltcbr = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
ltcbr.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

If i use QgsJsonExporter, the attributes order isn't preserved

```
#Bad order
exp = QgsJsonExporter(layer)
geojson = exp.exportFeatures(layer.getFeatures())

#Bad order
ogrLayer = QgsVectorLayer(geojson, 'Temp', 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(ogrLayer , False)
ltcbr = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
ltcbr.insertLayer(0, ogrLayer )
```

How to preserve attributes order in GeoJson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go another way e.g constructing the GeoJSON yourself with Python as I'm not sure you can control at PyQGIS level the attributes order for GeoJSON properties.

You will find below a recipe to illustrate how:

```py
# Get the layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# Get the provider
prov = layer.dataProvider()
# Get fields names with the order
fields = [field.name() for field in prov.fields()]
# loop to generate GeoJSON looping layer features properties and getting geometry as GeoJSON geometry format
geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": OrderedDict(zip(fields, i.attributes())),
        "geometry": i.geometry().asJson()
    } for i in layer.getFeatures()]
}

# If you want to write to an external file
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(geojson, outfile)
```

You may open [an issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) on QGIS project to support preserving attributes for `QgsJsonExporter`.

Comment: Thank you @thomasg77, It was the aIternative I had thought of. I also think that it is not possible to manage this with the native method in PyQGIS.